# Analyze my subtree algorithm?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, binary-tree

I'm trying to implement a function in Ruby to check if binary tree2 is a subtree of binary tree1. This is what I have so far -- it seems to work, but I'm not sure how scalable it is. Is this O(2^k) time? If so, any ideas how to optimize it? I'm assuming tree1 and tree2 are of a class Node with attributes data, left, and right.

```
def containsTree(tree1, tree2)
    if tree2.nil?
        return true
    if tree1.nil?
        return false
    if tree1.data == tree2.data
        containsTree(tree1.left, tree2.left) && containsTree(tree1.right, tree2.right)
    else
        containsTree(tree1.left, tree2) || containsTree(tree1.right, tree2)
    end
end
```

Comment: `data` are all unique in a tree, right?  because otherwise you need to worry about matching the "second value".

Comment: also, if you know `tree2.data`, doesn't that tell you which side of `tree1` to go down (if they don't match)?

Comment: data aren't all unique! if t1 contains the same values in the same order as t2 it's a subtree.

Comment: This is basically a code review question so you should post it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: unique *in a tree*.  if tree 1 contains 1, 2, 2, 3 and tree2 contains 2, 3 your code might match the "first" 2 in tree1 and then fail.

Comment: Are you missing return statements in front of the expressions in the `if` statements?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you could write something that traverses `tree1` looking for nodes whose data is the same as the root node data for `tree2`. When you find such a node, traverse the subtree starting at that node in parallel with `tree2`, checking to see if every node matches. You should reach the end of both trees at the same time.

Of course, there can be many nodes in `tree1` whose data matches the root node of `tree2`.

The algorithm would look something like this (not in Ruby):

```
// this method looks for nodes in tree1 that match the root node of tree2
traverse(node, tree2root)
{
    if (node == null) return
    if node.data == tree2root.data
        if check_trees(node, tree2root)
            print "tree2 is a subtree"
    traverse(node.left, tree2root)
    traverse(node.right, tree2root)
}

check_trees(tree1, tree2)
{
    if (tree1 == null && tree2 == null)
        return true
    if (tree1 == null || tree2 == null)
        return false
    if (tree1.data != tree2.data)
        return false
    if (!check_trees(tree1.left, tree2.left))
        return false
    return check_trees(tree1.right, tree2.right)
}
```

And you'd call it with:

```
traverse(tree1, tree2)
```

You'll need to add the early-out on the `traverse` method if you want it to stop once you've found a match.

This isn't terribly efficient in the general case, but should work reasonably well if there aren't too many nodes in `tree1` whose data matches the root of `tree2`.